# Cannot run a MySQL container, possible container not reading the variables set in the `.env` file

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I am having issue provisioning a docker container that will serve the MySQL for my drupal dev environment

**My Setup**

My `Docker version 18.01.0-ce, build 03596f51b1`

I have the following directory structure

```
.
├───.env
├───docker
│   └───drupal-mysql
│         └───Dockerfile
└───docker-compose.yml
```

My `.env` file:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
MYSQL_DATABASE=drupal-db
MYSQL_USER=drupal-user
MYSQL_PASSWORD=drupal-password
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
```

My `docker-compose.yml` for that container:

```
  drupal-mysql:
    container_name: drupal-mysql
    build:
      context: ./docker/drupal-mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=${MYSQL_DATABASE}
     - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - /usr/bin
    user: "1000"
    networks:
      - drupal-net
```

My `docker/drupal-mysql/Dockerfile` file:

```
# MySQL Container
FROM mysql:5.7

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

**Testing**

running `docker-compose config`:

```
networks:
  drupal-net:
    driver: bridge
services:
  drupal-mysql:
    build:
      context: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\mydrupalsite\docker\drupal-mysql
    container_name: drupal-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal-db
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal-password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: drupal-user
    networks:
      drupal-net: null
    ports:
    - 3306:3306/tcp
    user: '1000'
    volumes:
    - /c/Users/USER/Desktop/mydrupalsite/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    - /usr/bin
version: '2.0'
```

which means docker is reading the variables set in the `.env` file

**Start of issue**

but provisioning the container is failing:

```
USER@beepoPC0119 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/mydrupalsite (master)
$ docker-compose up -d
Starting drupal-mysql ... done

USER@beepoPC0119 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/mydrupalsite (master)
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                             NAMES

USER@beepoPC0119 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/mydrupalsite (master)
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                                             NAMES
cbee32c1ed5d        mydrupalsite_drupal-mysql   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Exited (1) 31 seconds ago                                                        drupal-mysql
```

as you can see the `docker-compose up` succeed, but issuing `docker ps` shows it got exited, this can be confirmed by issuing `docker ps -a`

**Possibilities**

I am thinking, the container is getting auto-exit because of this issue, if I run

```
$ docker run mydrupalsite_drupal-mysql
error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and 
MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

1. Now, its confusing me, why does the container said that the option
   for `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is not specified when in fact we did?

**Trying for solution**

Tried doing the proposed solution https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4189#issuecomment-274915631

but when I issue:

```
$ docker-compose config
networks:
  drupal-net:
    driver: bridge
services:
  drupal-mysql:
    build:
      context: C:\Users\USER\Desktop\mydrupalsite\docker\drupal-mysql
    container_name: drupal-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: $${MYSQL_USER}
    networks:
      drupal-net: null
    ports:
    - 3306:3306/tcp
    user: '1000'
    volumes:
    - /c/Users/USER/Desktop/mydrupalsite/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    - /usr/bin
version: '2.0'
```

as you can see it did not parsed the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` from `.env` file, and if I issue:

```
$ docker run mydrupalsite_drupal-mysql
error: database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
  You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD 
and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

it won't still run

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you add a `command: env` to the mysql service in yaml and see what values you get? Also use the single `$` as you want substitution at source

Comment: @TarunLalwani I got this output https://pastebin.com/raw/2aUQLMXq what are we looking for?

Comment: That means environment is getting password and the container didn't exist because of that. There is some other issue. You need to run `journalctl -f` in one terminal and run `docker-compose up` in another and see if you find an error which causes the container to exit.

Comment: Your command `docker run` doesn't read .env file it's only a behavior of docker-compose that's why it complains about missing env. Can you post the result of `docker-compose logs  drupal-mysql`. I suspect the volumes /usr/bin why did you create it ?

Comment: @MoiioM I got this: https://pastebin.com/raw/SF1zSzCe is there an error in that?

Comment: your logs contains only the result of the `env`. Can you rebuild your container without `command: env` ?

Comment: any update on this problem? Because I am having the same problem.